# loop over hash table of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, hash, hashtable

I have a hash table of arrays, ie:

```
function (findPairs) {

    var arrMaster = [];

    var hash = {

    a: [1,2,3,4,5],
    b: [2,3,5,7,9],
    c: [7,2,3,8],
    d: [1,2]

    }

   return arrMaster

}
```

My goal is to return an array that shows all pairs of keys who have three instances of a common element in their value array. eg, in above example:

- a and b share 2,3 and 5
- b and c share 2,3 and 7

I sketched out code in [JSFiddle](http://repl.it/1ql/4). **My main roadblock now is comparing a given  value array to all other value arrays - I have code that compares any array to the immediate successive array.** The code is getting quite complicated, with multiple nests, and frankly my head is spinning.

Comment: do you need to know exactly which elements are shared, or just the fact that they exist?

Comment: I'd return an array of arrays [[a,b], [b,c]], representing pairs of keys that met the conditions of having three shared elements. But as I see it, the intermediate step requires a temp array showing the exact shared elements.

Comment: no, it's perfectly possible to do it without actually creating the temporary array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think in smaller code chunks, i.e. how could you count the number of common elements in a pair of arrays:

```
function countCommon(a, b) {
    return a.reduce(function(p, c, e) {
        return p + (b.indexOf(c) >= 0 ? 1 : 0);
    }, 0);
}
```

Your problem is then reduced (no pun intended) to creating all possible pairs of the keys of `hash` and evaluating the above function for each key's data:

```
function makePairs(hash) {
    var result = [];
    var keys = Object.keys(hash);
    for (var i = 0, n = keys.length; i < n; ++i) {
        for (var j = i + 1; j < n; ++j) {
            result.push([keys[i], keys[j]]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

and then you just need the pairs that satisfy the criteria:

```
var result = makePairs(hash).filter(function(pair) {
    return countCommon(hash[pair[0]], hash[pair[1]]) >= 3;
});
```

Hey presto, only one nested loop!  Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/kxdngy7n/

Answer (score 0):

You could create an intermediate function to find the pairs like so:

```
function isPair(first, second) {
    var values = {},
        pairsFound = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < first.length; i++) {
        var str = first[i];
        values[str] = true;
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < second.length; j++) {
        if (values[second[j]] === true) {
            pairsFound++;
        }
    }

    return pairsFound > 3;
}
```